# Issu in Adwords API, Failed to refresh access token - "error" : "invalid_grant"

Tags: c#, api, google-ads-api

I am writing a code to get the search volume using adwords api in c# but it gives me the error on line "page = targetingIdeaService.get(selector);", below is my code, I found this code example online.

```
        AdWordsAppConfig config = new AdWordsAppConfig();
        config.OAuth2ClientId = "MY_OAUTH2ClientID Here";
        config.OAuth2ClientSecret = "MY_OAUTH2ClientSecret Here";


        AdWordsUser user = new AdWordsUser(config);
        AdWordsUser user1=new AdWordsUser()

        using (TargetingIdeaService targetingIdeaService = (TargetingIdeaService)user.GetService(AdWordsService.v201710.TargetingIdeaService))
        {

            TargetingIdeaSelector selector = new TargetingIdeaSelector();
            selector.requestType = RequestType.STATS;
            selector.ideaType = IdeaType.KEYWORD;
            selector.requestedAttributeTypes = new AttributeType[] {
                  AttributeType.KEYWORD_TEXT,
                  AttributeType.SEARCH_VOLUME,
                  AttributeType.AVERAGE_CPC,
                  AttributeType.COMPETITION,
                  AttributeType.TARGETED_MONTHLY_SEARCHES
                };
            List<SearchParameter> searchParameters = new List<SearchParameter>();
            RelatedToQuerySearchParameter relatedToQuerySearchParameter =
                new RelatedToQuerySearchParameter();
            relatedToQuerySearchParameter.queries = new String[] { keyword };
            searchParameters.Add(relatedToQuerySearchParameter);

            LanguageSearchParameter languageParameter = new LanguageSearchParameter();
            Language english = new Language();
            english.id = 1000;
            languageParameter.languages = new Language[] { english };
            searchParameters.Add(languageParameter);
            NetworkSetting networkSetting = new NetworkSetting();
            networkSetting.targetContentNetwork = false;
            networkSetting.targetGoogleSearch = true;
            networkSetting.targetPartnerSearchNetwork = false;
            networkSetting.targetSearchNetwork = false;
            NetworkSearchParameter networkSearchParameter = new NetworkSearchParameter() { networkSetting = networkSetting };
            searchParameters.Add(networkSearchParameter);
            selector.searchParameters = searchParameters.ToArray();
            Paging paging = Paging.Default;
            selector.paging = paging;
            TargetingIdeaPage page = new TargetingIdeaPage();
            try
            {
                do
                {
                    page = targetingIdeaService.get(selector); // gives error on this line
                    if (page.entries != null && page.entries.Length > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (TargetingIdea targetingIdea in page.entries)
                        {
                            Dictionary<AttributeType, Google.Api.Ads.AdWords.v201710.Attribute> ideas =
                                targetingIdea.data.ToDict();
                            long averageMonthlySearches = (ideas[AttributeType.SEARCH_VOLUME] as LongAttribute).value;

                            string keywordRes = (ideas[AttributeType.KEYWORD_TEXT] as StringAttribute).value;
                            Money averageCpc = (ideas[AttributeType.AVERAGE_CPC] as MoneyAttribute).value;
                            double competition = (ideas[AttributeType.COMPETITION] as DoubleAttribute).value;
                        }
                    }
                    selector.paging.IncreaseOffset();
                } while (selector.paging.startIndex < page.totalNumEntries);
                Console.WriteLine("Number of related keywords found: {0}", page.totalNumEntries);
            }
            catch (AdWordsException e)
            {
                throw new System.ApplicationException("Failed to retrieve related keywords.", e);
            }
        }
```

Please help what is wrong with my code or how I can achieve the functionality.
Thanks & Regards,

Comment: “invalid_grant” error means what ever adwords account you are using for this operation its not having permission to use adwords api.. you have to regenerate new refreshtoken for account which you wants to use and than it will work.

Comment: Thank you Vijaysinh for the response. do you know from where or how can i generate the refresh token, because while creating api credentials in google console, I didn't find any option of token, It just creates the api key, client ID and client secret.

Comment: You can take help of this url..but its php lib.

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/Auth/GetRefreshToken.php